# How preprocessor (i.e.#define) works?

Tags: c

I have the basic knowledge of preprocessor.But i have never understood how it works.Can some body explain me how it works?I would prefer practical explanation.Thank you.

Comment: Read some tutorials or Basic C programming book.

Comment: Most compilers have an option to stop after preprocessing, I think it would be highly educational if you, for some very simple program containing preprocessor macros, did that, stopped after preprocessing, to compare the preprocessed code with the original code.

Comment: One more thing, Preprocessor doesn't mean just `#define` . Its a type of preprocessor directive known as Macro

Comment: 'I would prefer practical explanation' - for a unique homework answer, I presume:(

Comment: This is a question best answered by a good reference manual; Harbison & Steele's [C: A Reference Manual](http://careferencemanual.com) devotes an entire section to the preprocessor, with plenty of examples.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In one of my assignment i have implemented simple pre-processor using c.I have used the simple hash table to store the name and its definition.
for example,

```
#define a 4
```

so here a is name and 4 is its definition.
So both a and 4 will be stored in the hash table.
now whenever in program name 'a' is encountered then it will be simply replaced by 4. 
i am posting my code in c for pre-processor.Which is very simple.But it would be very helpful for you to understand how pre-processor works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define HASHSIZE 101
#define BUFSIZE 100
#define MAXWORD 100

struct tnode {
    int loc[10]; // to store the locations at which words occur
    int i; // to store the index of array loc
    char *word;
    int count;
    struct tnode *left;
    struct tnode *right;
};

static struct nlist *hashtab[HASHSIZE];

int getword(char *word, int lim);
struct tnode *addtree(struct tnode *, char *);
void treeprint(struct tnode *);
struct tnode *talloc(void);

struct nlist {
    /* table entry: */
    struct nlist *next;
    /* next entry in chain */
    char *name;
    /* defined name */
    char *defn;
    /* replacement text */
};

char buf[BUFSIZE];
int bufp = 0;

unsigned hash(char *s);
struct nlist *lookup(char *s);
char *strdup1(char *);
struct nlist *install(char *name, char *defn);
int undef(char *s); // this function will remove entry

struct tnode *z[10]; // to store address of each node(word)
int total = 0;       // index for array z
char s1[1000];       // to store entire input
static int q = 0;    // index to s1

int main() {
    struct nlist *pt;
    char word[100];
    char name1[10];
    char defn1[10];
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    /*
    #define pi 5 is entered then...*/
    while (getword(word, MAXWORD) != EOF) {
        if (isalnum(word[0]) && (i == 0)) {
            if ((pt = lookup(&word[0])) !=
                NULL) // if name1(pi) is already present then replace it with its definition name(5)
            {
                strcpy(word, (pt->defn)); // if pi is alerady there then replace name by its definition
                // strcpy((pt->defn),word);
                for (k = 0; word[k] != '\0'; k++, q++) {
                    s1[q] = word[k];
                }

            } else // otherwise print the word
            {
                for (k = 0; word[k] != '\0'; k++, q++) {
                    s1[q] = word[k];
                }
            }
        }

        if (isalnum(word[0])) {
            if (i == 2) // copy word to defn1(i.e. defn1=5)
            {
                strcpy(defn1, word);
                install(name1, defn1);
                i = 0;
            }
        }
        if (isalnum(word[0])) {
            if (i == 1) // copy the word to name1(i.e. name1=pi)
            {
                strcpy(name1, word);
                i++;
            }
        }
        if (word[0] == '#') {
            if ((strcmp(word, "#define")) == 0) // if #define found then increase i to get next word(i.e. pi)
            {
                i++;
            } else {
                for (k = 0; word[k] != '\0'; k++, q++) {
                    s1[q] = word[k];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // printf("%d",i);
    // printf("%s %s",name,defn);
    // printf("%s",pt->defn);
    printf("%s", s1);
}
unsigned hash(char *s) {
    unsigned hashval;
    for (hashval = 0; *s != '\0'; s++)
        hashval = *s + 31 * hashval;
    return hashval % HASHSIZE;
}
/* lookup: look for s in hashtab */
struct nlist *lookup(char *s) {
    struct nlist *np;
    for (np = hashtab[hash(s)]; np != NULL; np = np->next)
        if (strcmp(s, np->name) == 0)
            return np;
    /* found */
    return NULL;
    /* not found */
}
/* install: put (name, defn) in hashtab */
struct nlist *install(char *name, char *defn) {
    struct nlist *np;
    unsigned hashval;
    if ((np = lookup(name)) == NULL) { /* not found */
        np = (struct nlist *)malloc(sizeof(*np));
        if (np == NULL || (np->name = strdup1(name)) == NULL)
            return NULL;
        hashval = hash(name);
        np->next = hashtab[hashval];
        hashtab[hashval] = np;
    } else
        /* already there */
        free((void *)np->defn);
    /*free previous defn */
    if ((np->defn = strdup1(defn)) == NULL)
        return NULL;
    return np;
}
char *strdup1(char *s) {
    char *p;
    /* make a duplicate of s */
    p = (char *)malloc(strlen(s) + 1); /* +1 for '\0' */
    if (p != NULL)
        strcpy(p, s);
    return p;
}
int undef(char *s) {
    struct nlist *np1;
    if ((np1 = lookup(s)) != NULL) {
        hashtab[hash(s)] = NULL; // delete the entry in array hashtab associated to s
        free(np1); // free memory allocated to s
        return 1; // if sucessful then return 1 else 0
    }
    return 0;
}
int getword(char *word, int lim) {
    int c, getch(void);
    void ungetch(int);
    char *w = word;
    while (isspace(c = getch())) {
        s1[q] = ' ';
        q++;
    } // takes the space in string s1
    if (c != EOF)
        *w++ = c;
    if (!isalnum(c) && (c != '#')) /*takes all character except #,digit and number in s*/
    {
        if (c != EOF) {
            s1[q] = c;
            q++;
        }
        *w = '\0';
        return c;
    }
    for (; --lim > 0; w++)
        if (!isalnum(*w = getch())) {
            ungetch(*w);
            break;
        }
    *w = '\0';
    return word[0];
}
int getch(void) /* get a (possibly pushed-back) character */
{
    return (bufp > 0) ? buf[--bufp] : getchar();
}
void ungetch(int c)
/* push character back on input */
{
    if (bufp >= BUFSIZE)
        printf("ungetch: too many characters\n");
    else
        buf[bufp++] = c;
}

/* addtree: add a node with w, at or below p */
struct tnode *addtree(struct tnode *p, char *w) {
    int cond;
    if (p == NULL) {
        /* a new word has arrived */
        p = talloc();
        /* make a new node */
        p->word = strdup(w);
        p->count = 1;
        p->left = p->right = NULL;
    } else if ((cond = strcmp(w, p->word)) == 0)
        p->count++;
    /* repeated word */
    else if (cond < 0)
        /* less than into left subtree */
        p->left = addtree(p->left, w);
    else
        /* greater than into right subtree */
        p->right = addtree(p->right, w);
    return p;
}

/* talloc: make a tnode */
struct tnode *talloc(void) {
    return (struct tnode *)malloc(sizeof(struct tnode));
}

void treeprint(struct tnode *p) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < total; i++)
        printf("%s", z[i]->word);
}
```

The code is self explanatory.Mind you it is very simple pre-processor.

Comment: Looks like the code sample doesn't live up to most expectations (seeing a few hardcoded limits that aren't going to suit real life applications).

Answer (score 1):

```
#define A 1234
```

Literally as far as the compiler is concerned, every instance of A is now 1234.

Its useful for code readability and modifieability. If you have a constant number for instance thats used in 7-8 different functions, you can #define it and use a *token* instead, and then change it in 1 place rather then 7-8.

Alternatives to using #define are using constant variables or enums.

```
#define myVar 755
const int myVar = 755;
enum{ myVar = 755 };
```

Are all functionally equivalent in most cases.

Comment: Not QUITE correct.  ABC doesn't become 1234BC. "CAT" doesn't become "C1234T".  Every *lexical token* of 'A' is now 1234.    An 'A' that was part of another token is just an 'A'.

Comment: @RussSchultz thats correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define MY_MACRO my_var
```

Everytime your compilator finds "MY_MACRO" in your code while creating the binary code, it considers you wrote "my_var".

Comment: Not literally *every* time. Consider `MY_MACROS = 5;`, which will *not* be interpreted as `my_varS = 5;`. Also, `printf ("MY_MACRO = %d", MY_MACRO);` – and many more cases.

Comment: Ho, I'll read about it, thanks for correcting me!

Answer (score -1):

The purpose of a `#define` is to give a value or macro a simple name that you can use in your program. This is called a *symbolic constant*. In stead of having to remember the value or retype the macro everywhere you need it, you define it once and use the name wherever you need. Also, to define for example the size of something (array, buffer), you define it once. Should you later need to change the size, you only need to edit the definition. These are only some examples of `#define`s.

The preprocessor reads the program text and replaces the macros and constants with their actual values. If a part of the program text is enclosed in `#ifdef...#endif` (conditional compilation) and the `#ifdef` evalates to FALSE, then that part is left out. In the next step the actual compiler compiles the resulting program text into actual code.

Comment: Great! Downvote withour providing a reason.